# mySQL database to use ID or to use TableName_ID

Tags: mysql

Im new to building databases and have seen both examples of using and ID field or changing the field to a related name such as user_id is this just preference?

Comment: The latter is the recommended way to go. When you'll be working with multiple tables you will need to be able to distinguish which table you're working on at the moment. E.g. user_id, product_id

Comment: ... which could be easily accomplished by aliasing tables and then for examples access the columns from `table t` as `t.id`.

Comment: and qualifying column references (with a table name or table alias) in statements that reference more than one table certainly aids the future reader. We don't require the reader to consult table definitions to figure out which table a particular column identifier is referencing. It also protects the statement from future changes by avoiding the introduction of "ambiguous column" errors when a duplicate column name is later added to another table referenced in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's a matter of personal taste. What I've come to find useful is to name the ID column `id`, but in tables where this is a foreign key, name it `table_id`.

For example, the ID column in the `users` table could be named `id`, but the foreign key in the table that assigns user rights to users it would be `users_id` to make clear that this is a reference to the `users` table.

Comment: Also, many ORMs and frameworks expect the id column to be called `id` - that can always be changed, but it's frequently the default.

Comment: Also, following this column naming scheme (primary key being `id` and foreign key being `table_id`) leads to normal join predicates following a pattern: `ON p.id = c.table_id`. Not that there's anything special about that pattern, but when we see a pattern like `ON p.id = c.id`, that looks sort of "wrong" to us, and when we see `ON p.table_id = c.table_id`, that looks like a shortcut join, from one foreign key to another. My opinion is that this helps out the future reader, and that there's more to it than just personal taste. Others will have different opinions.